# Restarting Apple AirPort Extreme with Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to run an applescript from Automator that restarts my AirPort Extreme. The Automator script is a Calendar Alarm type. When I run the script directly from Automator, it works just fine. When the calendar triggers Automator, I get the following:

> The action ”Run AppleScript“ encountered an error

I've made sure that the script itself, Automator, etc... all have access in Security and Privacy -> Accessibility. I've tried removing any `delay` from the applescript. I'm at a loss. I'd appreciate any ideas to help solve the issue. Thanks!

This is the applescript I'm trying to use with Automator:

```
activate application "AirPort Utility"
delay 4
tell application "System Events"
    click image 2 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "AirPort Utility"
    delay 3
    click menu item 3 of menu "Base Station" of menu bar 1 of application process "AirPort Utility"
    delay 1
    keystroke tab
    keystroke tab
    keystroke space
end tell
delay 300
tell application "AirPort Utility" to quit
```

Comment: Have you added calendar app, and airport utility to allow access also in accessibility preferences? Also maybe adding a delay between all of your keystrokes in the AppleScript?

Comment: Thanks. I've added airport utility. Will add calendar app. Also, I try adding some delays between keystrokes. I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

I added a try statement to your script and ran it directly from script editor with no problems at all.

---

```
activate application "AirPort Utility"
delay 4
tell application "System Events"
    try
        click image 2 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "AirPort Utility"
        delay 3
        click menu item 3 of menu "Base Station" of menu bar 1 of application process "AirPort Utility"
        delay 1
        keystroke tab
        keystroke tab
        keystroke space
    end try
end tell
delay 300
tell application "AirPort Utility" to quit
```

---

You can also try saving the script in script editor as an application, grant accessibility access to the new app, then just have Automator run that new app on the calendar event.

---

**Better yet, why not just bypass Automator completely? Again, in script editor, export that code as an app, granting accessibility access in system preferences.  Then you can run that file on a calendar event directly from calendar app.**

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want to avoid using Calendar.app, here is an interesting solution you may be interested in.  This following code, saved as an application in script editor, allows you to insert your desired time to launch any application you choose...

```
Run_Script_At_Specific_Time()

on Run_Script_At_Specific_Time()
    set theTime to time string of (current date)
    activate
    set requested_time to display dialog ¬
        "Please Enter Your Start Time With The Following Format: Hour:Minutes:Seconds" default answer theTime ¬
        buttons {"CANCEL", "OK"} ¬
        default button ¬
        "OK" cancel button ¬
        "CANCEL" with title ¬
        "Choose App Launch Time" giving up after 30
    set requested_time to text returned of requested_time
    activate
    set chosenApp to choose file with prompt ¬
        "Choose The App Or File You Would Like To Run At Your Specified Time" default location (path to applications folder) ¬
        invisibles false ¬
        multiple selections allowed false ¬
        without showing package contents
    repeat until theTime is greater than or equal to requested_time -- Added The "Greater Than" Just As A Failsafe
        delay 30
        set theTime to time string of (current date)
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        open chosenApp
    end tell
end Run_Script_At_Specific_Time
```

[image]

[image]